# Find a polynomial whose splitting field is $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha,i]$

Tags: polynomials, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $f(x)=x^{3}-3x+1$ and let $\alpha$ be a root in $f$.

i) Show that the polynomial $f$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.

ii) Show $\alpha^{2}-2$ is a root of $f$ as well, and show that all roots are real.

ii) Find a polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ whose splitting field is $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,i)$. Find all constructible numbers in $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,i)$.

I have done i) using Eisenstein with $x=x-1$ and ii) just by substituting in $x=\alpha^{2}-2$, however do not know where to start with iii).

Thank you for any help in advance.

Comment: If it were reducible, there would be a linear factor, and plus or minus one would be a root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hints:** Prove that $\mathbb Q(\alpha)\subseteq \mathbb R$ and conclude that $f(x)(x^2+1)$ has $\mathbb Q(\alpha ,i)$ as a splitting field. Find $[\mathbb Q(\alpha ,i)\colon \mathbb Q]=6$ and conclude, using the last statement in [this section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_number#Transformation_into_algebra), that the constructible elements in $\mathbb Q(\alpha ,i)$ are exactly the ones in $\mathbb Q(i)$.

Comment: That's great thank you.